# Objective C - Sketch Application will not draw long lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgcontext

I have an iPhone app where I provide a sketch pad for the user to save a signature. An UIImageView gets added to the main view and that holds the strokes.  For some reason you can only draw short lines on the pad like the following image.

[image]

I have another application for the iPad that uses the same code and it works fine.  I'm not sure what could be causing it.  I'm not using any touch or gesture code that would interfere with it.  The following is some of the code I use.

UPDATE: If I create a UIViewController with the same class and make it the root view controller then it works fine.  Something in my navigation hierarchy is doing something weird. [image]

```
-(void)SetUpSignaturePad{
//create a frame for our signature capture
imageFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                        self.view.frame.origin.y,
                        self.view.frame.size.width + 23,
                        self.view.frame.size.height + 7 );
//allocate an image view and add to the main view
    mySignatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    mySignatureImage.frame = imageFrame;
    mySignatureImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:mySignatureImage];
}

//when one or more fingers touch down in a view or window
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//did our finger moved yet?
fingerMoved = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

//we need 3 points of contact to make our signature smooth using quadratic bezier curve
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:mySignatureImage];
lastContactPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:mySignatureImage];
lastContactPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:mySignatureImage];


//when one or more fingers associated with an event move within a view or window
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//well its obvious that our finger moved on the screen
fingerMoved = YES;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

//save previous contact locations
lastContactPoint2 = lastContactPoint1;
lastContactPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:mySignatureImage];
//save current location
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:mySignatureImage];

//find mid points to be used for quadratic bezier curve
CGPoint midPoint1 = [self midPoint:lastContactPoint1 withPoint:lastContactPoint2];
CGPoint midPoint2 = [self midPoint:currentPoint withPoint:lastContactPoint1];

//create a bitmap-based graphics context and makes it the current context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageFrame.size);

//draw the entire image in the specified rectangle frame
[mySignatureImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height)];

//set line cap, width, stroke color and begin path
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 3.0f);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

//begin a new new subpath at this point
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), midPoint1.x, midPoint1.y);
//create quadratic Bézier curve from the current point using a control point and an end point
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                             lastContactPoint1.x, lastContactPoint1.y, midPoint2.x, midPoint2.y);

//set the miter limit for the joins of connected lines in a graphics context
CGContextSetMiterLimit(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);

//paint a line along the current path
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

//set the image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context
mySignatureImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

//remove the current bitmap-based graphics context from the top of the stack
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//if the finger never moved draw a point
if(!fingerMoved) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageFrame.size);
    [mySignatureImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height)];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 3.0f);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    mySignatureImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

//calculate midpoint between two points
- (CGPoint) midPoint:(CGPoint )p0 withPoint: (CGPoint) p1 {
    return (CGPoint) {
        (p0.x + p1.x) / 2.0,
        (p0.y + p1.y) / 2.0
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you that I haven't a real solution, but your problem most probably is due to performance issues. Why? Because you are creating an image each time a gesture is detected. Creating images requires of screen renderings that takes time and resources.
You should base your code on same project that has drawing functionalities, usually that use a view that updates their draw in the drawRect method, for you maybe a CAShapeLaywr is also fine.
Run Time Profiler in instruments and search wich method is tanking time.

Comment: I don't think it is a performance issue.  When trying to draw there is barely any increase in resource use.